# Sync client database with server

Tags: mysql, database

We have a database on client that have a `Category` and `Message` tables. Each record of the `Message` table has relation with `Category`'s record.

Category has three column

`id` `Ckey` `text`

Message has three columns

`id` `Ckey` `text`

Server database is same client database but `Message` and `Category` tables have extra column named as `username`

***Problem*** When I want to sync client database with server What should I do exactly ? On way is delete all records of username and insert new records. Another ways is updates exist record and insert new records. Which is better or better way exist?